# Rails query conditional on sum of children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How is best to produce a query in Rails (3.2) that returns a set of parent records dependant on the result of a sum of their children?

For example...

If and *Order* has many *Items*

How would you select all orders where the sum of Items.price (for an order) is greater than 50.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Order.joins(:items).
      group("items.order_id").
      having("SUM(items.price) > 50")
```

Comment: You'll need to change the `group_by` to `group`.

Comment: This looks the most promising, but I couldn't get this to work. It returned a nil set for some reason.

Comment: What do you mean by nil set?

Comment: Tell a lie, it works perfectly! My mistake putting it into my context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Order.joins(:items).where("SUM(items.price) > 50").all
```

This will make a single query to the database selecting all orders where the sum of the order items price is greater that 50.

**EDIT:**

This will not work. See comments.

Comment: This will not work as you are using a group function in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This query throws "Mysql2::Error: Invalid use of group function"